# Publish Nintex workflow programmatically

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I am trying to publish the workflow from a local folder to a list on site using nintex web services. I added the service reference in my visual studio solution. After that I tried to instantiate the object using

```
 NintexWorkflowService.NintexWorkflowWS objWFService = new NintexWorkflowService.NintexWorkflowWS();
```

but the service reference has no class for "NintexWorkflowWS". How can I publish the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Nintex makes use of a publishing API allowing you to reference the workflow instance ID, List Name, API key and location to the template itself.

You will need to ensure your parameters are correctly set before the call is successful.

You can do this in VS or use Postman to ensure your PUT is correct. Take a look at the API documentation in the help files for specific examples.